# Spring Boot - moving the application class

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

Upon moving a spring boot application main class (Refactoring) to a top level package, the application no longer works as before. It does seems like Security or property file related issue. I need help in resolving this. The application did not have these issue before the Main class was moved.

```
package com.erpproducts.core;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.erpproducts.core.db.repository")
@EntityScan("com.erpproducts.core.db.model")
public class FeesApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(FeesApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

> Stacktrace

```
2016-06-28 14:05:31.754 ERROR 29676 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'errorController': Error creating bean with name 'customErrorController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'debug' in string value "${debug}"; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customErrorController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'debug' in string value "${debug}"; nested exception is 
2016-06-28 15:03:34.702  INFO 36393 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-06-28 15:03:34.703  INFO 36393 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
2016-06-28 15:03:34.800  INFO 36393 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-06-28 15:03:35.075  INFO 36393 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-28 15:03:35.076  INFO 36393 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-28 15:03:35.076  INFO 36393 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-28 15:03:35.076  INFO 36393 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-28 15:03:35.077  INFO 36393 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2016-06-28 15:03:35.077  INFO 36393 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-06-28 15:03:35.248 ERROR 36393 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
```

POM XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.erpproducts.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>Fees</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Fees</name>
    <description>Fees component of ERP for Project FKS</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.M3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.erpproducts.core.FeeApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.activiti</groupId> <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId> 
            <version>5.19.0</version> </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId> <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId> 
            </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Post your project structure

Comment: Check the error message as it says: 'Could not resolve placeholder 'debug' in string value "${debug}"'. There is somewhere a `@Value("${debug}")` inside of either your code or the dependencies.

Comment: Are you using an embedded tomcat or deploying it?